# Run a call from a function PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, web

i'm building an website using php and html, im used to receiving data from a database, aka Dynamic Website, i've build an CMS for my own use. 
Im trying to "simplify" the receiving process using php and functions.

My Functions.php looks like this:

```
function get_db($row){
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$GLOBALS["db_host"].";dbname=".$GLOBALS["db_name"];
        $dsn = $GLOBALS["dsn"];
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pasw"]);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lp_sessions");
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach ($row as $row) {
                echo $row['session_id'] . ", ";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Could not connect to the database\n");
        }
    }
```

Where i will get the rows content like this: `$row['row'];`
I'm trying to call it like this:
the snippet below is from the index.php

```
echo get_db($row['session_id']); // Line 22
```

just to show whats in all the rows.
When i run that code snippet i get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\Wordpress ish\index.php
>   on line 22

I'm also using PDO just so you would know :)

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards
Stian

EDIT: Updated functions.php

```
function get_db(){
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$GLOBALS["db_host"].";dbname=".$GLOBALS["db_name"];
        $dsn = $GLOBALS["dsn"];
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pasw"]);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lp_sessions");
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo $row['session_id'] . ", ";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Could not connect to the database\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is on line 22? Is that the `echo get_db...` line?

Comment: Show the code in `index.php` that sets `$row`.

Comment: yes it is :)  10 char

Comment: What do you mean? this is what works when just calling get_db();

Comment: If you call `get_db($row['session_id'])` it has to get the value of `$row` before calling the function, and pass that element of it as an argument to the function.

Comment: Why does your function take an argument that it never uses?

Comment: Ah, how do i do that? Would be nice if you could give me some more guidance

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is the argument supposed to be for? The name `get_db()` suggests that it should return something, but all it does is print things.

Comment: Yes, when i run get_db(); it prints data from my database. This works like a charm. But i want to specify the row it pulls data from! Did this make it a little clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing the values from the DB, the function should return them as a string.

```
function get_db(){
    $dsn = "mysql:host=".$GLOBALS["db_host"].";dbname=".$GLOBALS["db_name"];
    $dsn = $GLOBALS["dsn"];
    $result = '';
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pasw"]);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lp_sessions");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $result .= $row['session_id'] . ", ";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Could not connect to the database\n");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
echo get_db();
```

Another option would be for the function to return the session IDs as an array:

```
function get_db(){
    $dsn = "mysql:host=".$GLOBALS["db_host"].";dbname=".$GLOBALS["db_name"];
    $dsn = $GLOBALS["dsn"];
    $result = array();
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pasw"]);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lp_sessions");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $result[] = $row['session_id'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Could not connect to the database\n");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then you would use it as:

```
$sessions = get_db(); // $sessions is an array
```

and the caller can then make use of the values in the array, perhaps using them as the key in some other calls instead of just printing them.

Comment: This worked sort of :) i dont get the error! I see now that i have handled it a bit wrong (my bad!!!!) i want to use it like: echo get_db($row['session_id']); and $row['data'] and $row['started'] all using the same function, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

As antoox said, but a complete changeset; change row to rows in two places:

```
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo $row['session_id'] . ", ";
        }
```

Putting this at the start of the script after `<?php` line will output interesting warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
```

To output only one row, suppose the database table has a field named `id` and you want to fetch row with id=1234:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lp_sessions WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "1234", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I chose PDO::PARAM_STR because it will work with both strings and integers.

Comment: Still the same: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\Wordpress ish\index.php on line 23